# Datetime without time textbox C# (Winform)

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm learning code so I have a problem that I want to show date from datagridview to textbox but I don't know how to show it without time. Thank you guys.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSnND.png)

Code I write `txtDate.Text = dataGrid.Cells[2].Value.ToString();`

I tried `txtDate.Text = dataGrid.Cells[2].Value.ToString("DD/MM/YYYY");`
It has erro " No overload for method 'ToString' ".

Thank you.

Comment: That value from a datagrid cell is an object. Try casting it to a DateTime, *if* you are sure it *is* a DateTime value

Answer (score 2):

Although it's unknow if your DataGridView has it's DataSource property set or not, consider using a [BindingSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource?view=windowsdesktop-6.0), set it's DataSource to say a [DataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=net-7.0) which in turn becomes the DataSource for the DataGridView. By doing so opens up the ability to have limited interactions with the actual DataGridView.

Now when you want to set the DateTime column value to a TextBox first check if there is a date and if a valid date exists retrieve it and format the value.

[image]

```
public partial class StackoverFlowForm : Form
{
    private readonly BindingSource _bindingSource = new();
    private readonly string _dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
    public StackoverFlowForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _bindingSource.DataSource = Mocked.Table();
        dataGrid.DataSource = _bindingSource;
        dataGrid.Columns["DateItem"]!.DefaultCellStyle.Format = _dateFormat;
    }

    private void GetStartDateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGrid.CurrentRow!.Cells["DateItem"].Value.IsNull())
        {
            txtDate.Text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            var dateTime = (((DataRowView)_bindingSource.Current)!)
                .Row.Field<DateTime>("DateItem");

            txtDate.Text = dateTime.ToString(_dateFormat);
        }
    }
}

#region Place these classes in separate files
public static class LanguageExtensions
{
    public static bool IsNull(this object sender)
        => sender == null || sender == DBNull.Value || Convert.IsDBNull(sender);
}
public class Mocked
{
    public static DataTable Table()
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();


        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn()
        {
            ColumnName = "Id",
            DataType = typeof(int),
            AutoIncrement = true,
            AutoIncrementSeed = 1,
            ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden
        });

        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = "FirstName", DataType = typeof(string) });
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = "LastName", DataType = typeof(string) });
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = "DateItem", DataType = typeof(DateTime) });

        dt.Rows.Add(null, "Jeanine", "Abbott",
            new DateTime(2018, 2, 12, 8, 0, 0));
        dt.Rows.Add(null, "Lester", "Lam",
            new DateTime(2018, 9, 8, 9, 0, 0));
        dt.Rows.Add(null, "Claire", "Cowan",
            new DateTime(2018, 1, 1, 10, 0, 0));
        dt.Rows.Add(null, "Karen", "Payne",
            new DateTime(2022, 1, 1, 10, 0, 0));

        return dt;
    }
} 
#endregion
```

There was a mention of using a [DateOnly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=net-7.0), but so no gain.

```
private void GetStartDateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGrid.CurrentRow!.Cells["DateItem"].Value.IsNull())
    {
        txtDate.Text = "";
    }
    else
    {
        var dateTime = (((DataRowView)_bindingSource.Current)!)
            .Row.Field<DateTime>("DateItem");

        txtDate.Text = DateOnly.FromDateTime(dateTime).ToString(_dateFormat);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to apply an overload of the ToString method that does not exist on a string.

You must first convert the initial string to DateTime like this:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dataGrid.Cells[2].Value.ToString()) && DateTime.TryParse(dataGrid.Cells[2].Value.ToString(), out DateTime date))
{
         txtDate.Text = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
}
```

An overload of the ToString is available by taking as a parameter the format

Comment: I don't like that ToString +  Parse combination. Better: `date = (DateTime) dataGrid. Cells[2].Value`

Comment: Yes, but in this case the code becomes a slave to the data.
On the assumption that the data is never null and always castable to DateTime I agree.
I assume that the application is not in control of the data and should avoid data-related exceptions at best.
If you are certain of data integrity why not use an explicit cast as you show.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using DateOnly.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dateonly?view=net-6.0

Or convert to string in the desired format output, by using:

ToString(dd/MM/yyyy)